# Monte Carlo Simulations Python

Tags: python, montecarlo

I am using Monte Carlo simulations to simulate a preservation system.
I have devices in my simulation with certain fail rate. Lets say the fail rate is 1/100000 meaning 1 out of 100000 devices fail each year. If the device fail I pay for the replacement. But I don't get how to catch the device failure randomly in the simulation. As I understand I need to use probability distribution to simulate this behavior. But I do not get how to do it.

Functions in random package seem to provide random number in a particular range which I do not have. Also I do not know what sort of distribution this is.

I hope the question makes sense to people. Any help will be appreciated.

Update on this:

I did this

```
    #/usr/bin/python
    import random 

    def main():
        count =0
        #fail rate is 1% of 100000, I need to do this probabilistically
        for _ in range(1,100000):
            x=random.random()
            if x <= 1.0/100000:
                count += 1

                print "x = "+str(x)+" fail device"
        print "device failed "+str(count)+"  times"

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

and I get output like

```
        x = 0.000743343826396 fail device
        device failed 1  times
        [Finished in 0.0s]
```

Thanks to timgeb for the help! However, I wonder if this behavior is the same as considering a fail rate of 1/100000?

Comment: No, it doesn't really make sense. Post some code and try to be more specific in what you are looking for.

Comment: *I hope the question makes sense* the real question seems to be missing! There are no question marks

Comment: `if random.random() < 1.0/100000: device.fail()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of failing devices per yer (or whatever unit of time) follows the Poisson distribution. If you have `n` units for `m` years, and the failure rate per year is `p`, then you can get a random number for the number of failing units by using `numpy.random.poisson`:

```
import numpy as np

n = 100000
m = 5
p = 1.0 / 100000

failed = np.random.poisson(n * m * p)
```

The function `np.random.poisson` will randomly determine the number of failing units. Run the last line several times to see what happens.

AFAIK, pure python does not have a Poisson distribution, even though it can be calculated with some maths from, say, Gaussian random numbers.

Comment: I am not able to ask further questions. Is it because of this question?